# Shared preference for Multiuser

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences, multi-user

In my app , to store data I am using SharedPreferences. I am able to add and retrieve data from SharedPreferences. My problem is when I switched to `New user`,SharedPreferences are not creating for `new user`. It is always fetching data from `owner` not from `Newuser`. How to create SharedPreferences so it should create both `owner` and `Newuser` ?

Thanks

Comment: change the shareprefrence key name for every new user so it store and fetch specific user data

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari Thanks for ur rply how to get new user ? I mean name or ID of the user?

Comment: use unique key like username for shareprefrence key so when user switch  it get the values from its corresponding  key

Comment: @PratibhaPatil, you have to manage user identifier to differentiate, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use like this.

```
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("first user",         MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("firstusername", "bcd");
     editor.putInt("password", 12);
       editor.commit();

   //for seconduser.

   SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = getSharedPreferences("second user", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
  editor2.putString("secondusername", "abc");
  editor2.putInt("password", 12);

  editor.commit();
```

//for retriving.

```
      SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences   prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
   String restoredText = prefs.getString("firstusername", null);
   if (restoredText != null) {
    String name1 = prefs.getString("firstusername", "No name defined");

//    for seconduser retriving
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences   prefs = getSharedPreferences("secon user", MODE_PRIVATE); 
   String restoredText = prefs.getString("secondtusername", null);
   if (restoredText != null) {
    String name2 = prefs.getString("secondtusername", "No name defined");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You would have user identifier to differentiate between owner and new user. If not then you have to maintain it.

You can use below single `SharedPreferences` util class to deal with all. I made it `singleton` and have used `enum` it to ensure `type-safety`.

```
public class SharedPreferencesUtil
{
    public enum KEY
    {
        FIRST_TIME_USER("first_time"),
        REGISTERED_USER("registered"),
        SKIPPED_REGISTRATION("is_skipped_registration"),
        DEVICE_INFO("device_information"),
        DEVICE_LATITUDE("device_latitude"),
        DEVICE_LONGITUDE("device_longitude"),
        ONLINE_APPS("online_apps");

        private final String value;

        KEY(String value)
        {
           this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue()
        {
            return this.value;
        }
    }

    private static SharedPreferencesUtil sharedPreferencesUtil = null;
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

    private SharedPreferencesUtil(Context context, String spName)
    {
        sharedPreferences = QCleaner.getInstance().getActivity().getSharedPreferences("mobi_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static synchronized SharedPreferencesUtil getInstance(Context context, String spName)
    {
        if(sharedPreferencesUtil == null)
        {
            sharedPreferencesUtil = new SharedPreferencesUtil(context, pName);
        }

        return sharedPreferencesUtil;
    }

    public boolean hasKey(KEY key)
    {
        boolean isKeyExist = false;

        /*if(sharedPreferences.contains(key.getValue()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(sharedPreferences.getString(key.getValue(), "")))
        {
            isKeyExist = true;
        }*/

        if(sharedPreferences.contains(key.getValue()))
        {
            isKeyExist = true;
        }

        return isKeyExist;
    }

    public boolean saveString(KEY key, String value)
    {
        return sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key.getValue(), value).commit();
    }

    public boolean saveInt(KEY key, int value)
    {
        return sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(key.getValue(), value).commit();
    }

    public boolean saveBoolean(KEY key, boolean value)
    {
        return sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key.getValue(), value).commit();
    }

    public boolean saveFloat(KEY key, float value)
    {
        return sharedPreferences.edit().putFloat(key.getValue(), value).commit();
    }

    public boolean saveDataLong(KEY key, long value)
    {
        return sharedPreferences.edit().putLong(key.getValue(), value).commit();
    }

    /*public boolean saveDataStringSetInSharedPreference(String key, Set value)
    {
        return sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet(key, value).commit();
    }*/

    public String getString(KEY key)
    {
        if(sharedPreferences.contains(key.getValue()))
        {
            return sharedPreferences.getString(key.getValue(), "");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(KEY key)
    {
        if(sharedPreferences.contains(key.getValue()))
        {
            return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key.getValue(), false);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public float getFloat(KEY key)
    {
        if(sharedPreferences.contains(key.getValue()))
        {
            return sharedPreferences.getFloat(key.getValue(), 0.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0.0f;
        }
    }

    public float getLong(KEY key)
    {
        if(sharedPreferences.contains(key.getValue()))
        {
            return sharedPreferences.getLong(key.getValue(), 0L);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0L;
        }
    }

    public boolean removeKey(KEY key)
    {
        boolean isDeleted = false;
        if(sharedPreferences.contains(key.getValue()))
        {
            isDeleted = sharedPreferences.edit().remove(key.getValue()).commit();
        }

        return isDeleted;
    }
}
```

**How to use this?**

```
SharedPreferencesUtil.getInstance(context, your_shared_preference_name).saveString(SharedPreferencesUtil.KEY.ONLINE_APPS, object.toString());
```

If you are using single name shared preference then you can customise it and you would not have to pass `context` and `sharedpreference` name each time.